# questions on polynomial Lagrange Interpolation of order $n$?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, analysis, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I ran in One Ex in my book when I‌ prepare for final exam on numerical method. how can help me how we solve such a problem?

if $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ be two polynomial Lagrange Interpolation of order $n$ in Nodal points {$‌ (x_i, y_i):i=0,...,n \}$ and   {‌ $(x_i, y_i):i=1,...,n+1 \}$. what is the  polynomial Lagrange Interpolation of at most order $n+1$ for nodal point  {‌ $(x_i, y_i):i=0,...,n+1 \}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to derive the answer you got. The polynomial you are after is given by (the standard Lagrange formula)

$$y(x) = \sum_{i=0}^{n+1} y_i\prod_{j=0,j\not= i}^{n+1} \frac{x-x_j}{x_i-x_j}$$

while the polynomials $P$ and $Q$ are given by (again just the standard Lagrange formula)

$$P(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n y_i\prod_{j=0,j\not= i}^n \frac{x-x_j}{x_i-x_j},~~~~~~Q(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} y_i\prod_{j=1,j\not= i}^{n+1} \frac{x-x_j}{x_i-x_j}$$

Now try to write them on the same form as $y(x)$ by making the product go from $j=0$ to $j=n+1$ in both expressions:

$$P(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n y_i \frac{x_i-x_{n+1}}{x-x_{n+1}}\prod_{j=0,j\not= i}^{n+1} \frac{x-x_j}{x_i-x_j},~~~~~Q(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} y_i\frac{x_i-x_{0}}{x-x_0}\prod_{j=0,j\not= i}^{n+1} \frac{x-x_j}{x_i-x_j}$$

Note that we can extend the upper summation limit to $n+1$ for $Q$ and the lower to $0$ for $P$ (since the summation term vanishes for this value). This gives

$$(x-x_{0})Q(x) - (x-x_{n+1}) P(x) = (x_{n+1}-x_0)\sum_{i=0}^{n+1} y_i\prod_{j=0,j\not= i}^{n+1} \frac{x-x_j}{x_i-x_j} = (x_{n+1}-x_0)y(x)$$

and it follows that

$$y(x) = \frac{(x-x_{0})Q(x) - (x-x_{n+1}) P(x)}{x_{n+1}-x_0}$$

As a double check of the result it is easy to calculate that $y(x) = y_i$ for all $i=0,1,2\ldots,n+1$.

Comment: Thanks nice hint, but my note say $ \frac {(x-x_0)q(x)-(x-x_{n+1})p(x)}{x_{n+1}-x_0}$ is the last answer ! would you please note me, how this result is gain from your hint !

Comment: would you please add more hint for me ?

Comment: This is the same as the answer you got, but it is not obvious (it follows since if two degree $m$ polynomials agree on $m+1$ points then they must be equal). Your answer is a much more simple and elegant solution. The idea is basically the same: the value of $q$ at $x=x_0$ is cancelled by a factor $(x-x_0)$ and the same at $x=x_{n+1}$. I will add some more details.

Comment: Wow, Very nice answer +1. I dont know about OP but for me it's not obvious !! how the answer of OP is equal with you? is it possible make it clearer in your answer?

Comment: @user153695 My original hint was a different (less elegant) construction, this answer is now the same as what OP has.

Comment: your are wrong :) please compare the formula in first comment with your answer :)

Comment: @user153695 It is exactly the same, it's just a different name for the polynomials. What I call $P$ he calls $q$ and so on. I have changed the names to avoid confusion.